# Data in storage is not modifying from thread

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

safe storage of data. I read that for this task suits Stackable. 
I inherit Stackable but data in storage is not synchronized.
AsyncOperation -- just incrementing value in storage
AsyncWatcher -- just making echo of value in storage.

Problem : data in storage is not modifying from AsyncOperation thread, storage permanently contains a -1.

I'm using pthreads.

```
class Storage extends Stackable {
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->local = $data;
    }
    public function run()
    {
    }
    public function getData() { return $this->local; }
}


class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
    private $arg;

    public function __construct(Storage $param){
        $this->arg = $param->getData();
    }

    public function run(){
        while (true)  {
            $this->arg++;
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}

class AsyncWatcher extends Thread {
    public function __construct(Storage  $param){
        $this->storage = $param -> getData();
    }

    public function run(){
        while (true) {
            echo "In storage ". $this->storage ."\n";

            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}

$storage = new Storage(-1);

$thread = new AsyncOperation($storage);
$thread->start();

$watcher = new AsyncWatcher($storage);
$watcher->start();
```

Comment: Can you use full sentences to describe what you did, what happened and what you expected to happen instead? It's far from clear what your actual question is...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, Sorry, English -- isn't my native language :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, [Stackable](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.stackable.php) class has a lot of methods, mainly used for async operations and they can help you with your issue. You should modify your async classes in this way:

```
class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
private $arg;

public function __construct(Storage $param){
    $this->arg = $param->getData();
}

public function run(){
    while (true)  {
        $this->arg++;
        sleep(1);
    }

    $this->synchronized(function($thread){
        $thread->notify();
    }, $this);
}
```

}

and their usage will be like this:

```
$storage = new Storage();
$asyncOp = new AsyncOperation($storage);
$asyncOp->start();

$asyncOp->synchronized(function($thread){
    $thread->wait();
}, $asyncOp);

var_dump($storage);
```